Euclidean space is a Lipschitz domain?
I'm reading the concepto of Lipschitz domain. For example, in

Question. Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a Lipschitz domain? i read that, the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the empty set. Is empty set a Lipchitz domain?
Thanks.

The author says that $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain, and $\Omega$ is a subdomain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

You have to check the definition in that reference. Sometimes boundedness is assumed for Lipschitz domains.
